# Can a json string contain HTML tags with it?

Tags: html, json

Consider this my json string,

```
[{
  "Mat_id": "2",
  "Mat_Name": "Steel",
  "Measurement": "mm",
  "Description": "Steel"
}]
```

Can i add HTML Tags inside this json string like this,

```
[{
  "Mat_id": "2",
  "Mat_Name": "Steel",
  "Measurement": "<bold>mm</bold>",
  "Description": "Steel"
}]
```

- Whether this is a valid json string?
- When Eval('('+ thisstring +')') will raise an issue? If so what is it?

I am doing so because i will pass this json object to a yui datatable which consumes json
datasource...

**EDIT:**

This my resulted json string,

```
{
  "Table": [{
    "Mat_id": "2",
    "Mat_Name": "Jully",
    "Measurement": "<bold>Inches</bold>",
    "Description": "Gully"
  }, ]
}
```

But i didnt get my Measurement column values in bold...

Comment: Good question...I was looking for it...I was almost sure that yes, but this thread confirms it. Thanks.

Comment: you can do like this,

{"Table" : [{"Mat_id" : "2",
"Mat_Name" : "Jully","Measurement" : "<b>Inches</b>",
 "Description" : "Gully"},]}

by this way, you can get your values in bold...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, yes, you can do that... practically, I'd be a bit concerned if there were HTML markup in my data.  What else might be in there?  Smells like an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @Aaronaught i didnt get my values of measurement in bold... Are my tags wrong?

Comment: If it's HTML, you should be using `<strong>`.

Comment: @Anon y we should use `<strong>` instead of `<bold>`

Comment: The idea is that `<strong>` indicates a general emphasis, rather than a specific style, like `<b>` tags do. You can change what each tag means through the use of CSS, but if you make a `<b>` tag italic, then the tag is lying about what it is. If you make a `<strong>` tag italic, then it still makes sense, semantically. By the way, the reason `<bold>` didn't work is because there is no `<bold>` tag in HTML, only `<b>`.

Comment: @Pandiya: You weren't too specific about how the tags are getting in there.  Normally the conversion from domain objects to JSON is done by some library, so either you're intercepting it or you're passing around unescaped HTML strings in your application.  Why don't you just use the YUI API to make the column/cell bold instead?  It's easy to skin.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah.. no problem with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

use Encoder.js from 
http://code.google.com/p/jsool/source/browse/jsool-site/js/util/Encoder.js?r=176

when getting data use

> Encoder.htmlDecode(value);

and when passing data use

> Encoder.htmlDecode(value);

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for >**Angular 2** compilation regarding parsing json containing html tags.

Below is the json containing html tags

```
{ 
 "data":"highlighting <b>this</b> in bold"
}
```

As you can see this is the keyword need to be bold in html while rendering.

If I use angular interpolation like below it will be parsed as normal string and <b> tag will be printed as it is.

```
   <p> {{titleDetails.what}}</p>
```

output : highlighting <b>this</b> in bold.

But if  you use property binding like below it will render the expected output.

```
   <p [innerHTML]="titleDetails.what"></p>
```

Output: highlighting **this** in bold