# Can JSON string contain greater than and less than signs?

Tags: html, json, validation

I have a JSON string that contains HTML, so it includes the greater than and less characters. Looks something like this...

```
  {
    "parameters": [{
    "name": "html",
    "value": "<tr>  <td align=\"left\">Hello Joe, what do you know? <td><tr>"
   }]
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151956/can-a-json-string-contain-html-tags-with-it) seems to indicate that such JSON is valid.

But [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) says it is invalid.

Who is correct?

I am also sending this JSON as a payload to an API which is choking on it. Which makes me also think there is something wrong with it.

Comment: I think you had a copy-and-paste error. When I pasted using the snippet you provided above into JsonLint, it is marked as valid. Your JSON is definitely valid.

Comment: "But JsonLint says it is invalid." —  http://i.imgur.com/0S6fA6Q.png — No, it doesn't.

Comment: "I am also sending this JSON as a payload to an API" — How? Try providing an [mcve]. Pay special attention to the "Verifiable" part!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.  I rm my xss filter, Then I get a vaild json. Yes, JSON string can includes the greater than and less characters.